# Hybrid graphic and laptop life

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

As a non-gamer I would like to get an answer on this question please. If a laptop use whole time integrated GPU, and switch to Nvidia when the system is demanding it, will it affect laptop's life in general?
Because as far as I heard, if the system uses integrated chip to deliver some HQ graphic/video it can "burn" up motherboard after some period (2,3 years ~). 
Is this true?﻿
I am running Xubuntu 14.04 with Intel HD Graphics 5500 + nVidia Geforce 920M 1GB. My BIOS don't let me to do any changes to it. I've got a new laptop and I am really concerned about my laptop life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some good news for you ... you do not have to be concerned about nor fear anything at all ! The information you have got that your motherboard will get "burned up" by the integrated intel graphics is wrong. There are a lot of computers that do not have a dedicated graphics chip and so are always running with the integrated graphics. The same is valid for the NVIDIA graphics, using it will not damage anything. Maybe the person who gave you the information unfortunately just had a hardware failure, which can happen as with every technical product. So just enjoy Ubuntu !